# How to debug a DLL file built in VC++ with Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-2006

I am a developer working on Delphi. In my project I have added a DLL file which is built in VC++. I need to debug the DLL file to fix some issues.

So what are the steps needed to follow in order to debug DLL file with Delphi code?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot debug the DLL from inside of Delphi, unless you do not mind stepping through the DLL's raw x86 assembly instructions. Otherwise, you need to load the DLL's source code into VC++ and use VC++'s debugger, specifying your Delphi application as the executable to use for the debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can also use Windows debugging tools (WinDbg) if you don't want to use VC++, but Delphi can't debug VC++ code because it has no support for its symbol files format.